# Value passed to the controller always null

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to pass a value to my controller but I think there is a timing issue.  On my view I have

```
window.location = "@(Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { id = "----", type = "0-0-" }))/".replace("----", id).replace("0-0-", type);
```

which gives a url of .../Controller/Action/100?type=4/

so the type is being set and is in the url but on the controller I have

```
public ActionResult Action(string id, int type)
```

and the id is populated but the type always comes in as null.  I am guessing the redirect is happening before type is being set.  I haven't run into this before and am baffled.  Any ideas why the controller isn't seeing type?

Comment: There shouldn't be a / in the end. It should fix it I guess.

Comment: @Yogesh,  I was wrong,  removed the slash and it worked.  Would you mind putting your comment in an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be a `/` in the end.